# App Crashes when switched from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When I start my app from landscape mode, it works perfectly. But when ever I try to switch from portrait to landscape mode, it crashes. I am using navigation drawer in portrait mode and linear layout in landscape mode.

code:

```
HomeMainFragment Mfrag;
HomeSideFragment Afrag;
DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); // Line 45  

    int screenconfig=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

     Mfrag=new HomeMainFragment();       
     Afrag=new HomeSideFragment();

    if(screenconfig==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){     
    drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.DrawerL);

 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fm_homesidefrag, Afrag).
    setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,   android.R.anim.slide_out_right).commit();       
    }               
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fm_homemainfrag, Mfrag).
        setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right).commit();
```

}

**Log:**

```
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.multipaneviews/com.example.multipaneviews.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at com.example.multipaneviews.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:45)
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    ... 12 more
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.multipaneviews.HomeSideFragment did not create a view.
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4266)
03-26 16:09:42.195: E/AndroidRuntime(24156):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
```

Comment: do you have alternative layout's for landscape and portrait modes?

Comment: Are you using Activity or FragmentActivity

Comment: are u using different layouts for landscape and portrait??

Comment: Yes I am using different layouts... and am using Activity

Comment: Please tell did you find the solution?